# Did the English place name "Frome" used to be pronounced as it is spelled?

Tags: pronunciation, literature, poetry, toponyms

The English town Frome is famously pronounced as "froom". The following is two stanzas from the dedication of G.K. Chesterton's poem *Ballad of the White Horse*, from 1911.

> Up through an empty house of stars,
> Being what heart you are,
> Up the inhuman steeps of space
> As on a staircase go in grace,
> Carrying the firelight on your face
> Beyond the loneliest star.
>
> Take these; in memory of the hour
> We strayed a space from home
> And saw the smoke-hued hamlets, quaint
> With Westland king and Westland saint,
> And watched the western glory faint
> Along the road to Frome.

Is this a little joke or poetic flourish, since *Frome* doesn't follow the rhyme convention perfectly? The rest of the poem seems very rigid with keeping the rhymes exact, so it definitely draws the attention. Or, was Frome actually pronounced as rhyming with *home* at some point in time?

Comment: In poetry and lyrics, you set up patterns and promptly break them. *Hour* and *home* do that already before we reach Frome.

Comment: In the US, it's pronounced to rhyme with *Rome*.

Comment: I'm not qualified to comment on the historical pronunciation of 'Frome', but I'm not convinced that 'hour' and 'home' are related in Chesterton's rhyme scheme, which apears to be a-b-c-c-c-b. There's also the minor point that in different parts of England 'hour' might be pronounced in one syllable as 'ah' or in two as 'ower'. I think Chesterton's home/Frome rhyme may be an example of visual rhyming, like find/wind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_rhyme